# Question of the Cholesky decomposition of symmetric positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, positive-definite

This is a exercise on my numerical analysis textbook:

> Suppose $\mathbf A$ is a positive-definite symmetric matrix, and the Cholesky decomposition is of the form $\mathbf {A} =\mathbf {LL}^{T}$, where $\mathbf L$ is a lower triangular matrix.
>   Prove the following statements:
>
> $$l_{ii}^2 \geq \min\frac{\mathbf x^T \mathbf A \mathbf x}{\mathbf x^{T} \mathbf x} = \frac{1}{\| \mathbf L^{-T}\|_2^2} \tag{1}$$
>
> $$l_{ii}^2\leq \max\frac{\mathbf x^T \mathbf A \mathbf x}{\mathbf x^{T} \mathbf x} = \| \mathbf L^{T} \|_2^2 \tag{2}$$
>
> $$\| \mathbf L^{-T} \|_2^2 \cdot \| \mathbf L^{T} \|_2^2 \geq \max_{1 \leq i,j\leq n}\frac{|l_{ii}|}{|l_{jj}|} \tag{3}$$
>
> where $\mathbf L^{-T}$ means the inverse and transpose of $\mathbf L$.

According the theorem of Rayleigh ([Rayleigh quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient)), I noted that

$$\|\mathbf L^{T}\|_2^2 = \lambda_{\max} (\mathbf A) = \max\frac{\mathbf x^T \mathbf A \mathbf x}{\mathbf x^{T} \mathbf x}$$

$$\frac{1}{\| \mathbf L^{-T} \|_2^2} = \lambda_{\min} (A) = \min\frac{\mathbf x^T \mathbf A \mathbf x}{\mathbf x^{T} \mathbf x}$$

However, I cannot find the relationship between the eigenvalues of $\mathbf A$ and the diagonal entries of $\mathbf L$, namely, $l_{ii}.$ Can anyone offer me a help? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo  Thank you very much for your editing! I should be more careful when presenting my question. It doesn't matter which matrices deserve \mathbf : )

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Sorry, I assume the matrices are real, so I have revised * to T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using properties of $\|\cdot\|_2$ norm we have
$$\|\mathbf{L}^T\|_2^2 = \|\mathbf{L}\|_2^2 = \max_{\|x\|_2=1}\|\mathbf{L}x\|_2^2 \geq \|\mathbf{L}e_i\|_2^2 = \sum_{j=i}^n l_{ji}^2 \geq l_{ii}^2 \,,$$
for any $i$.
Here $e_i$ denotes the $i$-th column of identity matrix. Similarly,
$$\|\mathbf{L}^{-T}\|_2^2 = \|\mathbf{L}^{-1}\|_2^2 \geq \|\mathbf{L}^{-1}e_j\|_2^2 \geq l_{jj}^{-2} \,,$$
for any $j$, because $\mathbf{L}^{-1}$ is lower triangular with $l_{11}^{-1},\ldots,l_{nn}^{-1}$ on its diagonal. 
This proves the first two statements.

To prove the third statement, we multiply the previous two inequalities and take maximum over $1\leq i, j\leq n$ to obtain $$\|\mathbf{L}^{-T}\|_2^2\|\mathbf{L}^{T}\|_2^2 \geq \max_{1\leq i,j\leq n}\frac{l_{ii}^2}{l_{jj}^2} \geq \max_{1\leq i,j\leq n}\frac{|l_{ii}|}{|l_{jj}|} \,.$$ The last inequality follows because maximum in both cases is obtained for some $i,j$ such that $|l_{ii}||l_{jj}|^{-1}\geq1$, for which $l_{ii}^2l_{jj}^{-2}\geq |l_{ii}||l_{jj}|^{-1}$

Comment: That is completely correct! I forgot to use the basic properties of norm. Thank you very much!

Comment: So we can prove the relationship between l_ii square and the eigenvalues of A as a by-product. Right?

Comment: Yes, the relationship between $l_{ii}^2$ and the eigenvalues of $A$ is just a consequence of this result and the result you got using theorem of Ryleigh.